# Android: App works on local device but not shown to that device on google play (SEND_SMS)

Tags: android

I am writing an app that needs to send SMS, if device support it, appart from Internet access and bluetooth communication. In the manifest I have these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

If I send the app to a 4.4.2 device using USB, everything works well. If I deploy that app on the google play, the same device can not see that app (meaning that it is not compliant with the device).

If I remove this line:

and deploy app on google play again, I can install it on the 4.4.2 device.

My question is:
Why does

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

permission works when app is deployd by USB but prevents app from being installed if using google play?

Thanks a lot
Imo

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#permissions

Answer (score 0):

```
 android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager smsManager = android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(91xxxxxxxxxx, null, "message", null, null);
```

Use this code to send text messages which gives you various choices over send the message through all possible messengers.
This code works on every platform.

Comment: Hi! Thanks. I have tryied using <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" android:required="false" />  then with <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/> but in eith case the app is shown in google play.  I also suppress these permissions and used code above but app asks me to shoose the channel to send message. I need to send SMS messages without user interaction. Please, help me one this

Comment: I meant "but in either case the app is not shown in google play"

Comment: try using <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />this will use the permission.But you need to allow the permission first .For the choosing the channel you can use the package name of the required application.If you need i can show you the usage of that.